# How to prevent the Bootstrap modal from closing when browser refresh is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Bootstrap modal window in my application. The modal window should not get close if the browser refresh functionality is done. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: once open set a `localStorage` value and on `document.ready()` check its value and open `modal` accordingly. change its value again when closed manually!

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using a cookie. When the page loads check to see if the cookie has the modal set as active. If so then load the modal.

So when you load the modal you would set the cookie.

```
var loadModal = function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    Cookies.set('isMyModalActive', true);
};
```

If you exit the modal remove it.

```
var exitModal = function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    Cookies.remove('isMyModalActive');
};
```

Finally on page load check if the cookie exists.

```
if(Cookies.get('isMyModalActive')) {
    loadModal();
}
```

I'm using [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) for brevity. You could easily replace [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) with [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [Document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

Comment: I'm getting a console error mentioning Cookies is not defined. Is that due to the plugin not supported??

Comment: It sounds like you have not loaded js-cookie. Have you followed this? https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/v2.0.3#installation You don't need js-cookie though. This page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie provides good information on working with native cookies. (i.e. no libraries)